# TOR routing and TOR vs VPN

Tags: routes, vpn, tor

I just watched a video about what a [VPN is and how it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGjGQ24cXAY) and how [TOR works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRYzre4bf7I). Although I think I understand both well, I am quite confused on what the key difference is, because to me, TOR is just a VPN on steroids.

From what I can tell from the video about VPN, you send a request to another server and that server sends a request on your behalf, masking your IP and tricking the server to think the VPN server is making the request on your behalf. Is this not the equivalent of the exit node on the TOR network, but TOR will be much more encrypted and therefore just be better?

On that side note, another question about routing. When the packets are being sent over the TOR network every node knows about the node it received from and the node it is sending to. What are the values of the `source IP` over the packet being sent over the network at each node. Let's assume now I am in a TOR network sending a request to server `a:b:c:d`, the `dest:ip` for the packet throughout the path will always be `a:b:c:d`, but how does the `src:ip` change at each stage to hide who originally sent it?

It makes sense to me during request, but sending backwards is a tad confusing. Sure, every node sends it to another node until eventually the request is made from the exit node, but is each request completely independent? Once the packet is passed to another node, doesit store the `src:ip` of the previous node who passed it the packet and hold that `src:ip` until the node is passed it to passed it back? Haven't found an example that is this indepth before.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Basically the technical difference with TOR x VPN is that with TOR you have a bunch of TOR relays connected to each others(currently it's around 6000 relays). [https://metrics.torproject.org/networksize.html ].

"Onion Routing is a distributed overlay network designed to anonymize TCP-based applications like web browsing, secure shell, and instant messaging. Clients choose a path through the network and build a circuit, in which each node (or "onion router" or "OR") in the path knows its predecessor and successor, but no other nodes in the circuit. Traffic flows down the circuit in fixed-size cells, which are unwrapped by a symmetric key at each node (like the layers of an onion) and relayed downstream. The Onion Routing project published several design and analysis papers [27,41,48,49]."
[https://svn.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.html ]

In VPN It's just into and out of the tunnel that encryption takes place (its secure enough for 99% of the time, IF YOU TRUST  in the VPN-provider), but unlike the TOR if your VPN-provider is not trusted, the system administrator can register and access data such as source address, destination address, websites that you is accessing, time, date...With the TOR is not possible to do that thanks to its design. A series of circuits are formed, where in each circuit performs a function:

**GUARD** - it knows the ip provided by your provider and middle ip.

**MIDDLE** - only knows the ip of the guard and exit (next hop)

**EXIT** - only knows the middle and next hop ip (newcircuit)

**note that exit is not the same as exit relay, it's just an output to the next circuit.**

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples to oranges in a sense. A VPN sits at your network adapter level and tunnels all of your traffic through another network where it then exits and relays its responses back through that network to you. A conventional proxy (of which Tor is a unique type) is configured at an application level to do roughly the same task. Think of a VPN as a global proxy for every packet using any protocol exiting your computer.

Tor is a proxy service that you configure your applications (browsers and such) individually to talk through. The unique thing about Tor as a proxy provider is the network you go through is dynamically layered instead of consisting of just a single middle man. This provides greater anonymity instead of just relying on the logging policy of your VPN provider but increases latency and again is usually configured application by application instead of globally.

Most VPNs are not layered at all or at least not to that extend but they also tend to have much less latency and allow you to choose what boils down to your exit node while tunneling all of your public traffic through them instead of just traffic you configure.

By the way, serverfault might be a better stack exchange for this sort of question since it's not really related to programming (that's probably where the downvotes are coming from).